# Form[] default value in scala template

Tags: forms, playframework-2.0, scala-template

I try to define defaul value for scala template parameter, like:

```
@(user: Form[User] = Form[User])
```

And I see compilation error:

```
object play.data.Form is not a value
```

whats wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately it doesnt work like this, you have to define the Form's presentation. You may have in your User class:

```
val requestForm = Form(
    mapping("field1" -> nonEmptyText,
      "field2" -> nonEmptyText)(User.apply)(User.unapply))
```

And then you can use your template like this:

```
@(user: Form[User] = User.requestForm)
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank's. I saw this construction in documentation, but I missed that it must be in my class.